# Throwing an exception for a invalid number of fields in a csv record

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am writing a parsing method for a csv record and want to throw an exception if the number of fields in the record do not match the expected length.

What exception should I throw?

Comment: You should consider using the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class which can throw [MalformedLineExceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.malformedlineexception.aspx).

Comment: Do you need more information or can you accept an response as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own exception class with expected/actual fields

Answer (score 2):

This is really down to personal choice, you could create one of your own if you wish, it depends how engineered you want it to be.  There is a InvalidDataException in System.IO

Answer (score 1):

If you want a built in one [InvalidDataException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.invaliddataexception.aspx)  is a good choice. Description:

`The exception that is thrown when a data stream is in an invalid format.`